# Javascript Error on Custom Button Single Quote in Name

Tags: javascript, error-messages

I have a custom Javascript button on the Case object that creates an Opportunity. I am getting the error:

*"A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered: 
missing ) after argument list"*

The error message occurs when the Contact record Name includes a single quote (e.g., D'Ambro).  Does anyone know what I can do to fix?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")}
if (typeof(srcUp) == 'function')
{
srcUp('/006/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&RecordType=012a0000001Fsxa&opp11=Quote&00Na000000BODU0=Small Quote&opp3={!Case.Account} - Quote&opp9={!TODAY()+30}&CF00Na000000BAz6W={!Case.Contact}&ent=Opportunity');
}
else
{
window.open('/006/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&RecordType=012a0000001Fsxa&opp11=Quote&00Na000000BODU0=Small Quote&opp3={!Case.Account} - Quote&opp9={!TODAY()+30}&CF00Na000000BAz6W={!Case.Contact}&ent=Opportunity');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_scontrols.htm):

> **JSENCODE**
>
> Encodes text and merge field values for use in JavaScript by inserting escape characters, such as a backslash (`\`), before unsafe JavaScript characters, such as the apostrophe (`'`).

Try updating your `{!Case.Contact}` references to `"{!JSENCODE(Case.Contact)}"` in your `window.open` and `srcUp` method.